# How to validate Complex types Forms using jquery form plugin and data annotations in Asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form having multiple text boxes and dropdown lists created with generic list:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",FormAction.POST))
 {
  <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Dropdown</th>
       <th>TextBox</th>
      </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
       @for(int i=0;i<Model.GetList.Count();i++)
       {
         <tr>
          <td>@Html.DropdownListFor(x=>x.GetList[i].SelectDOC,(SelectList)ViewBag.Items)</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.GetList[i].INPUT)</td>
         </tr>
        }</tbody></table>
  }
```

**Model Class**

```
public class modelclass
{
  [Required]
  public int SelectDOC{ get;set;}
  [Required]
  public string INPUT{get;set;}
  public List<modelclass> GetList { get; set; }

}
```

As above jquery form is not working because name attribute for element will be different and server validation is also not working.

Is it possible to validate this type of form using jquery form plugin or MVC validation?

Comment: What do you mean _"form is not working"_? What is not working. What is the method you are posting back to? (and the `name` attribute is supposed to be different - model binding would not work other wise). You also don't appear to have `@HtmlValidationMessageFor()` for any properties or `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to display any validation messages

Comment: "not work":- As suppose a textbox have name="FirstName", we can validate by specifying in rules in jquery form , but here we will have as name for each textbox name="GetList[0].FirstName", how should validate this type of textboxes in jquery

Comment: So I assume that means you are not using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` which does this all out of the box?

Comment: Yes, I am not using unobstrusive because my form is not ajax begin form()..!!

Comment: Whats `Ajax.BeginForm()` got to do with anything associated with validation. Add the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file to you page and add `@HtmlValidationMessageFor(x=>x.GetList[i].INPUT)` (ditto for `SelectDOC`) and you will get client side validation. As for server side validation, you need to show your controller since you must have a mistake in your code if its not working.

Comment: I can only assume your getting mixed up with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` with is for client side validation, and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` which is associated with the `Ajax` helpers